# Replace whole words only

Tags: emacs24.4, ubuntu

I want to replace all occurrences of a word in the whole buffer. What i do is:

```
M-x replace-string RET word-to-be-replaced RET new-word
```

The problem with this is that it also changes the `word-to-be-replaced` even if its only part of another word (for example wanting to change *mod* to **off_mod** results also changing *set_mode* to set_**off_mod**e). How can i change it only in cases it exists exactly as a whole word  and not also as parts of other words?

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 13):

If you provide the universal argument to `replace-string`, that is by pressing `C-u` before `M-x replace-string`, it only replaces matches that are surrounded by word boundaries.

So, for example, a buffer containing

```
mod
set_mode
```

would be become after `C-u` `M-x replace-string RET mod RET off_mod`

```
off_mod 
set_mode
```

---

You can find this information by looking in the manual: `C-h i` (to get the `info` index) `m Emacs RET` (to open the Emacs user manual section) and finding "replace-string" through the topic index by doing `i replace-string RET`.

Alternatively, you could look-up the function's documentation by doing `C-h f` `replace-string`

Comment: +1, especially for teaching about the manual. Also: `C-h r` takes you to the Emacs manual, where `i replace-string` takes you directly to the doc about `replace-string`. **`i`** is your friend in Info.